# jQuery val not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this simple jQuery init function, works in Firefox but not in Chrome

```
function init() {   
    var produtoCabal;
        produtoCabal = localStorage.getItem('produtoCabal').replace(/\'/g,"");;
        jQuery("#produtoCabal").val(produtoCabal);
}
```

Edit1: Here where's the function called:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', init);
```

No error in console

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: when is this function called?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @ErrorinException edited

Comment: `Event.observe` is a [prototypeJS designation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/). Use `window.onload = function() {...}` or `$(window).load(function() {...})` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Observe() is a prototype function. You may be using a 3rd party library (like tapestry) that removes prototype and replaces it with jQuery. Try  to change observe() to on()
Also try putting the script tag at the end of the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope this helps!